# Formatting JSON string to include carriage returns

Tags: json

I am attempting to format a string in JSON which forms the body of an email generated by an http request to SharePoint. The string includes dynamic data from Microsoft Forms responses and this is picked up fine.  No matter what I attempt to add to the JSON code (inside the " "), and in the first image I am trying '/n',the output is a continuous string with no carriage returns.  Screen shots of the code (with the sort of spacing I am attempting to replicate in the output) and output are attached (SharePoint link redacted).  If anyone was able to tell me how I can replicate the carriage returns in the output, I would be grateful. The string forms the content of a property called 'Body'
[JSON code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcTP.jpg)
[JSON output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BesTi.jpg)

I have tried including /n and /r code but these make no difference and I suspect I am misusing the code.  I have also tried to break down the string into smaller arrays - each contained within "" and separated by a ',' but similarly no luck. The http request is part of a Power Automate flow which generates an incident notification message.

Comment: it looks like renders as html did you try <br> tag?

Comment: I haven't actually tried the <br> tag.  If I was to, where would I put it; at the appropriate points in the string?  I tried adding <p> and <\/p> to the beginning and end of the string to try and infer this was html and thus keep the formatting but these were ignored in the output so I rather feel that anything inside the string ".." may similarly be ignored.  I do think that including html formatting may be the way to go even if I have to perform this separately and reference the output of this in the final step.  Your support is appreciated.

Comment: where you need a line break , try for test for one record - put <br><br> tags and see if it render as expected.

Comment: Spot on. It works.  Thank you very much.  That all seemed too simple.